# Can a WCF web service access raw SOAP message Header and Body as XML data?

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, wse

I need to build a web service in C# which will receive a SOAP 1.1 message where the `<Envelope><Header>` and `<Envelope><Body>` will contain only complex XML data.

In WSE (according to [this Microsoft page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa528828.aspx)), creating a SOAP web service to handle this type of message seems fairly straight forward :

```
class MyReceiver : SoapReceiver
{
    protected override void Receive(SoapEnvelope message)
    {
        // Do something with the message
        // such as display its contents.
    }
}
```

But, since WSE is being depreciated, I would like to build this service using WCF.

The WCF examples I find, though, seem to be of the variety where a specific set of parameters are passed to a specific method.

```
[OperationContract]
string GetData(int value);
```

Is there a way using WCF to create a web service which can receive raw SOAP 1.1 messages and provide access to the `<Envelope><Header>` and `<Envelope><Body>` sections as XML elements or XML streams?

Answer (score 0):

To process raw SOAP messages you should use [`Message`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734675%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class, which represents raw message. Simply create your operation contract that accepts and returns it:

```
public Message ProcessMessage(Message msg);
```

then you will have `Message.Headers` or `Message.GetBody` methods. There is also a `Message.Version` if you want to check if it is whether SOAP 1.1 or 1.2.

Comment: I am having trouble finding details on how to configure the Web.config file for this type of endpoint.  All the soap examples assume parameters are being passed.  Can you help me out with an example?  I have created a class with a [ServiceContract] attribute and the ProcessMessage method with an [OperationContract] attribute.